# document.cookie is null for ajax get request using phonegap

Tags: jquery, android, ajax, cordova

I am writing my first android app using **PhoneGap** (modeled along the PhoneGapHelloWorld sample) and **jQuery**. I use a **AJAX GET** request to my django server and it responds with a **csrftoken** cookie. I can see this cookie in the Fiddler output of HTTP Response Header but when I try to access it inside the javascript code using **document.cookie**, it returns null. Experts, please help!!!

Please find all the relevant code fragments and outputs below.

- **Response Header (from Fiddler output)**

> HTTP/1.0 200 OK Date: Sun, 29 Apr 2012 18:25:46 GMT Server:
>   WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.2 Last-Modified: Sun, 29 Apr 2012 18:25:46
>   GMT Expires: Sun, 29 Apr 2012 18:25:46 GMT Content-Type: text/html;
>   charset=utf-8 Vary: Cookie Cache-Control: max-age=0 Set-Cookie:
>   **csrftoken**=97c5b4b7b39ef7f54e09a55157b5ae9e; expires=Sun, 28-Apr-2013 18:25:46 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/ Set-Cookie:
>   sessionid=b1d29d8a6adc02be41e8cc3951b791fb; Path=/

- **Javascript (jQuery)**

```js
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onSuccess(data, status, xhr) {
        alert(document.cookie);
    }

    function onDeviceReady() {
       $.ajax({type : 'GET',
          url: "http://someurl.com/",
          success: onSuccess
         });
    }
```

Comment: did you ever get an answer to this man?

Comment: I had the same problem as well, I figured out that the cookies were getting stored in the browser even though I was not getting them in my phonegap js code.

Comment: I'm having this issue in the regular Android browser (2.3.7): normal HTML gets pass the cookie back, but $.ajax requests do not.